# How do I setup shadow-cljs for code reload with Cordova + Clojurescript?

Tags: android, cordova, clojurescript, shadow-cljs

I am currently working on a sample app on `Cordova` with `Clojurescript`. I am using `shadow-cljs` to build the project but somehow I could not find a way to make the **code reload** to work.

Instead, I have to use the *browser* build when developing since it allows for a shorter feedback loop with the *code reload*. And then after that, I deploy the app to a device/emulator using the `cordova` command line.

Is there a way in `shadow-cljs` to make the *code reload* to work while using the device/emulator directly when developing ?

Answer (score 3):

I created a [simple example](https://github.com/thheller/cordova-cljs) using `shadow-cljs` with Cordova. I only tested the `windows` runtime but I'd assume that the others work as well.

It is all regular `shadow-cljs` the only special tweak in the config file is the `:use-document-host false` since by default it will try to use `document.location` and figure out where to connect from there. On Windows at least that is some `ms-appx://` URL which cannot be used to connect the `shadow-cljs` websocket. So we disable the default which will make it use `localhost` instead. This works fine for Windows but other platforms might require tweaking the [:devtools-url](https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#proxy-support) config option in case the generated "app" does not run on the same machine (eg. mobile device or emulator).